# Selenium webdriver doesn't open application url

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I created a testing framework by using selenium `webdriver` and i was running the same in **Firefox 44.0.2** and 2 days back it was working fine.
But now it opens the firefox browser but doesn't navigate to mentioned url in .get method, below is my url navigation code and the exception which i m getting :-

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://seleniumpractise.blogspot.in/2016/08/how-to-use-explicit-wait-in-selenium.html");
```

Exception:-

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7056 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
sions\\fxdriver@googlecode.com","installDate":1474450844360,"updateDate":1474450844360,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":false,"size":3213569,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":true,"hasBinaryComponents":true,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"3.0","maxVersion":"45.0"}],"targetPlatforms":[{"os":"Darwin","abi":null},{"os":"SunOS","abi":null},{"os":"FreeBSD","abi":null},{"os":"OpenBSD","abi":null},{"os":"WINNT","abi":"x86-msvc"},{"os":"Linux","abi":null}],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"signedState":0}
1474450846803   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating XPIState for {"id":"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","syncGUID":"4YrFqCoch9_A","location":"app-global","version":"44.0.2","type":"theme","internalName":"classic/1.0","updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{"32":"icon.png","48":"icon.png"},"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Default","description":"The default theme.","creator":"Mozilla","homepageURL":null,"contributors":["Mozilla Contributors"]},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","installDate":1473742108164,"updateDate":1473742108164,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"skinnable":true,"size":24172,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"44.0.2","maxVersion":"44.0.2"}],"targetPlatforms":[]}
1474450846803   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1474450846804   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1474450846805   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1474450846805   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1474450846806   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1474450846819   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1474450846820   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1474450846820   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1474450846820   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1474450846820   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1474450846820   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1474450846832   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1474450846833   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1474450846833   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1474450846833   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1474450846833   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1474450846833   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1474450847985   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1474450847985   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1474450847986   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1474450848873   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1474450849387   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1474450849387   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1474450849393   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1474450849415   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1474450849415   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1474450849416   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1474450849420   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1474450849420   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
1474450849457   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1474450849470   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:117)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at dd_core.page.init(page.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:510)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:211)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:296)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:259)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1185)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1110)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1018)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

i added `selenium-java-2.48.2.jar`. pls suggest!!

Comment: Can you please try updating Firefox version to 46

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine with FF 46.0 try updating the ff version.

Comment: @All:- Just updated my FF version to 46.0.1 but it throws same above exception.

Comment: can u share the list of .jar files which you have used?

Comment: @all:- thanks:- by updating my selenium jars files to 2.53.1 version issue gets resolved. Added:- selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar and selenium-java-2.53.1.jar issue gets resolved!!

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time it's happening because of browser version just upgrade your version and run your code again